# Is there an Nginx equivalent to apachectl fullstatus?

Tags: nginx, command, status

I am looking for an Nginx command that will output more detailed information in a manner like `apachectl fullstatus` command does for Apache.

Is there an equivalent to that Apache command for Nginx?

Thank you in advance.

Tried https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html

Need more detailed information, possibly per worker as that Apache command outputs.